Shasta Daisy Next Bud
Hi and thank you for your time.
My Shasta daisies need to be deadheaded but I don't see the next bud anywhere. I put my glasses on and I check everywhere, but I don't see any new buds.
Any suggestions??

Do you need to see buds? Generally, there's no connection between deadheading for more flowers and spotting buds there already.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sounds like it's time to give your Shasta daisies some TLC. Don't fret about not spotting new buds right off the bat, that's totally normal.
Here's the thing:
We gardeners know deadheading is like magic for these cheerful fellas. By snipping off those spent blooms, we're sending a message to the plant: "Hey, forget about making seeds, focus on pumping out more flowers!" Even if you don't see new buds peeking out yet, trust me, they're getting the memo.
Here's how to tackle it: grab your pruners and snip that spent bloom just above a healthy set of leaves. This might not be where a new bud is visible, but it's the prime spot to trigger fresh growth. Bonus tip: cutting back the stem a bit can actually encourage the plant to put out side shoots, which means even more flowers down the line!
Your Shasta daisies might not thank you right away, but they're resilient little things. Within a week or two, you should start seeing new growth and those beautiful blooms popping back up. In the meantime, if you want to see some folks deadheading Shasta daisies in action, just search for it on YouTube – there's a ton of great videos out there!
